# mysql connector for django 1.9

Tags: mysql, django

I updated from django 1.7 to **django 1.9**, created new project and app inside it. Now I want to **connect with mysql** for this app **using mysql connector specifically**(dont want to use mysqlDB or mysqlclient). I am using python3.4 for development. DATABASE settings in settings file looks like this -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
    }
}
```

I created a model -

```
class Zipcode(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

But while **migrating the database** I am getting this error -

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1264: Out of range value for
>   column 'applied' at row 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Out of range value for column 'applied'
>   at row 1

However this works properly with django 1.7 and 1.8.

> I know there are compatibility issues while connecting to mysql using
>   mysql connector but I wanted to ask if someone has gone through this
>   error and fixed it?

Mysql version - 5.5
Connector version - 2.1.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the same problem with django 1.10.2 and mysql connector 2.1.4

Comment: Generic mysql connector have support till Django1.8, you can you MySQLdb, I think this is the only option for now. Source-https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/

Comment: yep, thanks for that